# Does this character rejoin the squad?

Tags: mass-effect-3

Ashley got all healed up and on her feet again, and I was expecting her to be somewhere on the Normandy after leaving the Citadel, but she's nowhere to be found.  I talked to Udina, but his answer was just that she's become a Spectre, the first of many since the war broke out, apparently.  Doesn't she know she's more than welcome on board?  Especially since I romanced her in the first game and remained loyal during the second.

Comment: Could you please rephrase the title? It just spoilered me.

Comment: @Sentry: Do you have a suggestion?  I feel that's less of a spoiler than earlier events, plus it's much more descriptive.

Comment: How about leaving the name out, just "Will you-know-who rejoin my squad after becoming a spectre?" and then put the name of the character in the question in spoiler tags.

Comment: @Sentry: So it's not the fact that they become a Spectre that spoiled you, but rather that they had to leave your squad?  I'm sorry, but that happens so early in the game, and considering the game's been out for over a year, I have no sympathy for you.  If you don't want to be spoiled, ignore the tag.

Comment: Dude, calm down, no need to be rude. I've just completed Mass Effect 2, so the fact that this character becomes a Spectre is a massive spoiler for me. It doesn't matter how early this happens, it is a spoiler and you should rephrase the title, it is not that hard.

Comment: @Sentry: I assure you, in the grand scheme of things, the fact that they become a Spectre is so minor that it's not something you should be too worried about.  And I say again, if you don't want to be spoiled, ignore the tag.  I'm not trying to be rude, but you're not being very helpful by suggesting a good replacement.  Titles are meant to be descriptive and precise, which this one is.  If you have a problem with that policy, you can bring it up on meta.

Comment: Since I didn't play the game, yet, it's hard for me to suggest a better title. But you're right in that ignoring the tag would be better for now, maybe I'll come back when I've played it and have a better idea for a title.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The answer is yes, Spoiler:

> but it will be *after* the assault on the Citadel by Cerberus.
> Eventually, Ashley/Kaidan will be fully healed but will be recruited by Udina to be a bodyguard for the Councilors; Ashley/Kaidan is unaware that Udina and Cerberus are working together to lead the Councilors into a trap so Udina can take control of the Council. This puts Shepard and Ashley/Kaidan in conflict; Shepard must then convince Ashley/Kaidan into realizing the truth about what's going on and turning on Udina instead. If Shepard cannot persuade Ashley/Kaidan to back off, then Shepard can kill Ashley/Kaidan. If not, a squad member will shoot her/him.
> If Ashley/Kaidan lives past this event, Shepard has the option of either recruiting her/him back onto the Normandy and into the squad, or of leaving her/him behind to assist with the War Effort.

[**Source**](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Kaiden#Mass_Effect_3)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, they will after a certain event. Spoiler:

> After Cerberus attacks the Citadel

Answer (score -1):

Yes. To do so, you MUST have done all of the following:

1. Save the ORIGINAL Council in Mass Effect 1.

   - If you let the Council die, then in ME2 and ME3 the NEW Council feels that you would  put human interests before galactic concerns (something Cerberus would do).
2. Visited them at the hospital all 3 times.

   - While comatose.
   - Awake but injured.
   - On their feet awaiting discharged.
3. (Optional) Romance them.

   - Stay faithful to them in ME2.
   - If pursued new love interest in ME2, apologize to them or tell them why you left them.
4. (Optional) Give them a "get well soon" gift.
5. If BOTH, or either, Thane or Kirrahe are alive and spoke to both of them. Then when Kai Leng tries to kill the Salarian Councilor, Thane or Kirrahe will jump in and save the councilor. If the Salarian Councilor was saved by either of them, Udina has no "evidence" of his own to frame you with.
6. Depending on the dialogue you choose when confronting Udina, Kaidan/Ashley, and the turian and asari councilors - take the interrupt.

Comment: Your first step is incorrect, I let the council die and Ashley still joined.

Answer (score -1):

As far as if Ashley or Kaiden return to the Normandy, they don't have to but yet, there is the option to get them back. Just keep playing the story, I can't say any more than that without spoilers. What I can say though, is you won't be able to miss the conversation that determines this.